# Запуск диалогового окна в отдельном потоке и управление им по таймеру на python

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, raspberry-pi, таймер, gtk

Программа работает на одноплатнике Raspberry, на python.
Мониторит состояние пина. Если на пине появился сигнал, открывается диалоговое окно и ждем реакции пользователя. Параллельно нужно продолжать мониторить тот же пин. Если в течение 3 секунд на нем вновь появился сигнал, то все ок, продолжаем ждать реакции пользователя (он может нажимать кнопки в диалоге, что вызывает другие окна и т.п.). Если же в течение 3 сек сигнал на пин не поступил, диалог (и все прочие открытые окна) надо зарыть. Далее ждем опять сигнал, показываем диалог, мониторим пин и т.п. Т.е. диалог работает при условии, что не реже раз в 3 сек на пин поступает сигнал.

Как я понимаю, тут нужен таймер на 3 сек, который запускается в отдельном потоке. Таймер нужно обнулять, если пин изменил состояние и снова засекать 3 сек. Если 3 сек прошли, вызывать колбэк, который будет делать Gtk.main_quit(). Как-то так. Но это по сути моя вторая программа на питоне )). Т.е. я с потоками не очень (мягко говоря).

```
import gi
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from threading import Thread, Timer

def gui_close():
   print('Убираем GUI')
   Gtk.main_quit()
 
def gui_open()
   print('Открываем GUI')
   dialog = GtkDialog()
   dialog.show_all()
   Gtk.main()

tmr = Timer(3, gui_close)
def signal_detected():      
   #здесь нужно обнулить (запустить заново) таймер
   #и запустить поток с GUI,
   #если он еще не запущен      

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
SIGNAL_PIN = 12
GPIO.setup(SIGNAL_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(SIGNAL_PIN, GPIO.FALLING, callback=signal_detected)
```

Пожалуйста, знающие люди, помогите разобраться с потоками ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTK не работает в потоках. Маин обычно запускается на все время работы программы и не закрывается до выхода. Показ окна осуществляется через `show`, скрывается через `hide`. Нет особой нужды создавать новые окна.

Ваш код переносится в поток. Взаимодействие с GUI же строится только через вызов `gobject.idle_add`

Таймер встраивайте в окно и запускайте вместе с show. Хотя лучше его убрать и использовать `GObject.timeout_add`

Comment: Спасибо, в целом разобрался, переделал код, убрал таймер и добавил timeout_add, все получилось довольно логично и работает норм. Но остался вопрос: изначально я поместил show и hide в соотв. методы (коллбэки) объектов. Т.е. при нажатии на кнопки в диалоговых окнах они сами закрывают/открывают себя и другие нужные окна. И параллельно выполняется мой код в отдельном потоке. Это норм? Или нужно и внутри объекта использовать idle_add?

Comment: Наверное какую-то фигню написал, просто пока не до конца разобрался )

Comment: idle_add используется в основном при вызове из побочного потока, иногда при вызове тяжелых функций в основном потоке.

Comment: внутри объекта только для рекурсии

Comment: Понял, спасибо.